# XML get value based on a changing parameter/variable

Tags: c++, xml

I am writing a XML file and I need to specify some parameter values according to a condition depends on a parameter will be assigned by my application in run time.

some thing like that

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IF x >= 3>
<THEN> <Length>4</Length></THEN>
<ELSE> <Length>5</Length></ELSE>
</IF>
```

and I need to set the value of x from my qt c++ application every time I query on the length value

Is this possible?

Comment: You should state your values in the XML file, and your app should keep the logic to select one or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's software, so anything is possible...

But, what you've described is certainly not easy, and there's almost certainly a better way of doing it.

From the XML snippet, it's like you want to store some code in an XML file, and then  'execute' it at run-time, giving it access to C++ variables like 'x' and 'Length'.

You *could* do this by embedding (for example) a [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) interpreter in your application, binding C++ objects, functions and variables to Lua, and then storing a Lua 'snippet' within an XML file. All possible, but a pretty large job. This is hugely powerful, and therefore potentially insecure and dangerous.

But generally, you'd want to keep logic in your code, and data in the XML. So the values "3", "4" and "5" might be data, but the code to interpret how to use them belongs in C++

```
 <xLength testValue="3" resultGt="4" resultLe="5"/>
```

C++ pseudocode -

```
int testValue = xml.getAttr("testValue");
if (x >=  testValue)
   Length = xml.getAttr("resultGt");
else 
   Length = xml.getAttr("resultLe");
```